# Concatenating NSArray contents with NSMutableString AppendString

Tags: objective-c, iphone, string-concatenation

I'm trying to iterate through an NSArray and keep getting a compiler error right when i try concatenating the contents of my array at position i to my NSMutableString instance..

It just tells me that there's a "syntax error before ;" which doesn't tell me a whole lot.
at this line:

```
  [output appendString:[widget.children objectAtIndex:i];
```

i know there must be something up with my syntax..

my function is as follows

```
- (NSString *)readArray
{
    NSMutableString *output = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    int i;
    int arraySize = widget.children.count;
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    for (i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        [output appendString:[widget.children objectAtIndex:i];  (throws error here)
    }
    [pool release];
    return output;

}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have an unclosed bracket
you need `]]` at the end instead of `]`

Answer (score 13):

`NSArray` has a method that does exactly what you're doing as well:

```
- (NSString *)readArray {
    return [widget.children componentsJoinedByString:@""];
}
```

Also, unless you're calling that function fairly frequently in a tight loop there's not much advantage to having it create its' own autorelease pool.